# Differential Equations - How to solve a logistic growth model with the added mean

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, economics, biology

For the general logistic growth model that can be applied to biology and economics

$\frac{dP}{dt} = gP(1-\frac{P}{K})$

I know to separate the variables and divide by $P(1-\frac{P}{K})$ resulting in $ln(p) - ln(1-\frac{p}{k}) = gt + A$. Then just rearranging to find p.

That I understand fine, however when another term is added, uP or anything involving P, I do not know how to separate the variables.

For example how do I separate
$\frac{dP}{dt} = gP(1-\frac{P}{K}) + uP$

I cannot seem to find a way to get it to result in all Ps on one side  without horrendous mess and trying to integrate

$\frac{1}{(gP(1-\frac{P}{K}) +uP)}$

Comment: But what do I divide by? Dividing by the original $P(1-\frac{P}{K}) $ would result in frac{uP}{P(1-\frac{P}{K})} = frac{u}{(1-\frac{P}{K})} on the right hand side so all P's wouldn't be on the left for separation of variables

Comment: Thanks alot can't believe I missed that simple factorisation mine was very very messy, I expanded it into a quadratic and tried partial fractions.

Comment: I think I separated it incorrectly, for the original, 

$dP(\frac{P}{P(1-\frac{P}{K})})$

Becomes

$\frac{1}{gP} + \frac{\frac{1}{gK}}{1+\frac{u}{g}+\frac{P}{K}}$

However I'm not sure how to do that for this one, 

is it $\frac{1}{gP} + \frac{\frac{1}{gK}}{1+\frac{u}{g}+\frac{P}{K}}$

Sorry, not sure why my brain is struggling to do simple stuff, haven't done calculus for a while chosen mainly stats modules for the last year.

Comment: Yes sorry, Shouldn't be Dp(P) should be Dp(1)

Comment: Sorry I noticed I put the same formula in twice for the original and my guess

Comment: I am just unsure how to ingegrate that, for the original example it's split into $\frac{1}{P} + \frac{\frac{1}{K}}{1-\frac{P}{K}}$ Which I can integrate

Sorry I know it's probably very simple

Didn't see your second part, I will try partial fractions

Comment: Really sorry to keep asking for more help but I tried partial fractions and not sure it right. 

$\frac{1}{BgP} + \frac{1}{Bg(P-BK)}$

This integreates to become $ln(\frac{P}{P+\frac{uK}{g}{+1}})$

Perhaps that is right then the exponential would be $\frac{P}{P+\frac{uK}{g}{+1}} = Be^t$

Comment: you have made  a little sign mistake its $$\frac{1}{BgP} - \frac{1}{Bg(P-BK)}$$ You're really close to the correct solution.

Comment: Yes! Sorry I knew it was minus that's how I simplified the logs. I am aware that the log should have $\frac{1}{1+\frac{u}{g}}$ before it is that everything?

Comment: Put the $Bg$ constant on the other side before to integrate. It's more simple.

Comment: Thankyou! I am terrible at differential equations, every year I have one module with them in and struggle every time. Mainly stick to statistics

Comment: You're welcome. You did a good job dont worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both DE are Bernoulli's differential equations:
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = gP(1-\frac{P}{K}) + uP$$
$$P'-P(g+u) = -g\frac{P^2}{K}$$
By integrating factor method we get:
$$(Pe^{-(g+u)t})' = -g\frac{P^2}{K}e^{-(g+u)t}$$
$$\int \dfrac {d(Pe^{-(g+u)t})}{P^2e^{-2(g+u)t}} = - \frac{g}{K}\int e^{(g+u)t}dt$$
It's easy to integrate now.
$$ \dfrac 1{Pe^{-(g+u)t}} =  \frac{ge^{(g+u)t}}{K(g+u)} +C$$
$$ \dfrac 1{P} =  \frac{g}{K(g+u)} +Ce^{-(g+u)t}$$

---

With fractions decomposition method:
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = gP(1-\frac{P}{K}) + uP$$
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = gP(1+\dfrac ug-\frac{P}{K}) $$
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = gP(B-\frac{P}{K}) $$
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = \dfrac g KP(KB-P) $$
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = \dfrac g KP(A-P) $$
$$\int \frac{dP}{P(A-P)} = \int \dfrac g K dt$$
Where $A=BK=K(1+\dfrac ug)$.
$$\dfrac 1 A \left(\int \frac{dP}P-\int \dfrac {dP}{(P-A)}\right) = \int \dfrac g Kdt$$
Now integrate.